# Only show 2 random data on each value

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, ajax

This is the code I use to display data from database and filter "Provider " categories with "searchByProvider". Under Provider there is a lot of data, but I want to show only 2 random data that show when someone selected "Provider"?

`your text`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>document</title>
      <!-- Datatable CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.13.1/datatables.min.css"/>
      <link href='DataTables/custom.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <!-- jQuery Library -->
      <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Datatable JS -->
      <script src="DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body >
      <div >
         <!-- Custom Filter -->
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <select id='searchByBrand'>
                     <option value=''>-- Select Brand--</option>
                     <option value='Coolcasino'>Coolcasino</option>
                     <option value='Schnellwetten'>Schnellwetten</option>
                     <option value='Lightning'>Lightning</option>
                     <option value='Happyslots'>Happyslots</option>
                     <option value='Payoutz'>Payoutz</option>
                     <option value='Instawin'>Instawin</option>
                     <option value='Quickbet'>Quickbet</option>
                  </select>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <select id='searchByProvider'>
                     <option value=''>-- Select Provider--</option>
                     <option value='4ThePlayer'>4ThePlayer</option>
                     <option value='Bad Dingo'>Bad Dingo</option>
                     <option value='Big Time Gaming'>Big Time Gaming</option>
                     <option value='Boomerang'>Boomerang</option>
                     <option value='Booming Games'>Booming Games</option>
                     <option value='Dicelab'>Dicelab</option>
                     <option value='Electric Elephant'>Electric Elephant</option>
                     <option value='Evoplay'>Evoplay</option>
                     <option value='Fantasma'>Fantasma</option>
                     <option value=''>Games Lab</option>
                     <option value=''>High Flyer Games</option>
                     <option value=''>Inspired</option>
                     <option value=''>Isoftbet</option>
                     <option value=''>Jelly</option>
                     <option value=''>Just For The Win</option>
                     <option value=''>Kalamba</option>
                     <option value=''>Max Win Gaming</option>
                     <option value=''>Microgaming</option>
                     <option value=''>Netent</option>
                     <option value=''>NoLimit City</option>
                     <option value=''>Northernlights</option>
                     <option value=''>Peter and Sons</option>
                     <option value=''>PG Soft</option>
                     <option value='Play N Go'>Play N Go</option>
                     <option value=''>Pragmatic Play</option>
                     <option value=''>Print Studios</option>
                     <option value='Quickspin'>Quickspin</option>
                     <option value='Red Tiger'>Red Tiger</option>
                     <option value='Reflex Gaming'>Reflex Gaming</option>
                     <option value='Relax'>Relax</option>
                     <option value='Relax Gaming'>Relax Gaming</option>
                     <option value='Silverback'>Silverback</option>
                     <option value='Slingo'>Slingo</option>
                     <option value='Spearhead'>Spearhead</option>
                     <option value='STHLM Gaming'>STHLM Gaming</option>
                     <option value='Yggdrasil'>Yggdrasil </option>
                  </select>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
         <!-- Table -->
         <table id='empTable' class='display dataTable'>
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th>Brand</th>
                  <th>Provider</th>
                  <th>Product</th>
                  <th>URL</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
         </table>
      </div>
      <!-- Script -->
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
             var dataTable = $('#empTable').DataTable({
                 'processing': true,
                 'pageLength': 10,
                 'serverSide': true,
                 'serverMethod': 'post',
                 //'searching': false, // Remove default Search Control
                 'ajax': {
                     'url':'ajaxfile.php',
         
                     'data': function(data){
                         // Read values
                         var Provider = $('#searchByProvider').val();
                         var Brand = $('#searchByBrand').val();
         
                         // Append to data
                         data.searchByProvider = Provider;
                         data.searchByBrand = Brand;
                     }
                 },
                 'columns': [
                     { data: 'Brand' },
                     { data: 'Provider' },
                     { data: 'Product'},
                     { data: 'URL', render:function (dataField) { return '<a target="_blank"  href="' + dataField + '">Game Link</a>'; } },
                 ]
             });
         
             $('#searchByBrand').change(function(){
                 dataTable.draw();
             });
         
             $('#searchByProvider').change(function(){
                 dataTable.draw();
             });
         });
         
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

in the talbe 4 column(Brand,Provider,Product,Url) Brand and Provider show as filter. I want to show when someone filter with Brand with show only 2 random data from Provider and also want to show always randomly
Is this possible?
Please help me.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `order by rand() limit 2` to retrieve **2** **random** records from the db table

For example, if the select query (in your `ajaxfile.php`) is like

```
select [fields...] from [tablename] where [conditions]
```

then change to

```
select [fields...] from [tablename] where [conditions] order by rand() limit 2
```

Comment: ## Fetch records
$empQuery = "select * from tablename WHERE 1 ".$searchQuery." order by ".$columnName." ".$columnSortOrder." limit ".$row.",".$rowperpage;
$empRecords = mysqli_query($con, $empQuery);
$data = array();

Comment: I am using this code but don't have knowledge about it. can you should i do next?

Comment: So just change `order by ".$columnName." ".$columnSortOrder." limit ".$row."` to `order by rand() limit 2` (you are displaying two random records only, so further ordering seems not necessary)